# Laravel, get info from another table inside foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have foreach loop that get info from 'items' table from db.

```
@foreach($puzzles->chunk(4) as $items)
  <div class="row">
   @foreach($items as $key => $data)
    <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
     <img class="card-img-top" src="http://localhost/beta/public/thumbnails/{{$data->avatar}}" alt="Card image cap">
     <div class="card-body">
       <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
       <span class="badge badge-primary">{{$data->maker}}</span>
       <span class="badge badge-primary">{{$data->count}} pcs</span>
    
       <p class="card-text">{{$data->location}}</p>
       

       <div class="dropdown">
       <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  Offer Exchange
      </button>
  
   <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">


    @foreach($items as $key => $data)
      @if($data->uid = '1') 
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ $data->id }}</a>
     @endif
   @endforeach

   </div>
  </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
@endforeach
```

So i tried to do like this

```
@foreach($items as $key => $data)
      @if($data->uid = '1') 
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ $data->id }}</a>
     @endif
   @endforeach
```

But as you imagine this does not work

So i have table ITEMS, where i can get all the data out what i need.

Then i have a button that has a dropdown and on that dropdown it should show the ITEMS that the user own, but for that i need the USER ID to check if ITEMS UID(UsersID) is the same as USER ID

And then display the outcome on that dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Dump `$data` and see what it returns object or array. Also why not loop like this

```
@foreach($items as $item)
```